# How to put a HAProxy node to maintenance via configuration file?

Tags: haproxy

Is there a way to configure HAProxy to add a node to the configuration but keep this particular node in maintenance? Just like with the web interface?

Reason behind is, that I have the same setup as in production on a development cluster and I would want to only have one node up during development but keep the config available. Right now I have to change the status upon boot of the machines.

config:

```
    server www-1 10.0.0.120:80 cookie S1 check
    server www-2 10.0.0.130:80 cookie S2 check
    server www-3 10.0.0.140:80 cookie S3 check
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to enable node S3, while others are in backup state:

```
    server www-1 10.0.0.120:80 cookie S1 check backup
    server www-2 10.0.0.130:80 cookie S2 check backup
    server www-3 10.0.0.140:80 cookie S3 check
```